# How does one deal with asynchronous login?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using `Parse` API for my app and I am going to be using the `ParseUser` object to maintain a user database. At the beginning, the user will be logged in using the `logInInBackground()` method.

Now, say that the connection is slow and the login is taking time or as soon as the user hits the sign up / sign in button, he gets a call and the activity is suspended. The call can go on for a long time (if the user is a blabber mouth) while the login/signup process continues in the background.

If it is successful, a new `Activity` is to be started or if it fails, an error message is to be displayed. However, since the `Activity` is suspended, **how do I deal with it?**

Do I keep some booleans, update `SharedPreferences` or what?

I know that in `onPause()` and `onStop()` background tasks have to be stopped.

Reference: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/?com/parse/ParseObject.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the User logon section of Rest API docs.

It walks u thru the process of submit a logon that sends a TOKEN in the response.

Note that at parse.com that token NEVER expires.

One usage on the client with a perpetual lease on the token is that you only have to log one time on one client. After that, assuming you do not need to switch among users, the SharedPreference persistence layer can keep the parse user token value for when its needed.

No logon step is necessary because any subsequent parse request can be accompany by the token.

I always use REST api. IMO parse only needs the token and not something like a user session.

Comment: Oh, not that! I mean when the `Activity` is suspended when the callback is invoked, what do I do?